# changing array values recursively in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I'm trying to change the values of an array recursevely and all the examples that I've seen in stackoverflow don't fit for what I want so far.

Basically, I want to translate a boolean to String.

```
foreach($this->data as $key=>$value)
{
    if (is_bool($value))
    {
        $this->data[$key] = var_export($value, true);
    }       
}
```

This works just in the first level of the array. Also, I've tried to change the values with `array_walk_recursive` with no success as well.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

[array_walk_recursive()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) should do this perfectly easily

```
array_walk_recursive(
    $myArray,
    function (&$value) {
        if (is_bool($value)) {
            $value = 'I AM A BOOLEAN';
        }
    }
);
```

[Demo](http://3v4l.org/nCMK3)

Comment: The `&`(by reference) was what I'm looking for, thanks!

Comment: That's what I was looking for

Comment: thanks for answer,Is there any way can change value depending upon another key element's value of same array

Comment: @rahul not with this function.  At most, you can find the visited leaf node (value) and its key (if you pass it into the callback), if you need access to a greater portion of data while recursively iterating, you will need to design your own custom function.

Comment: @rahulsingh yes you can. like this: 

`array_walk_recursive($myArray, function($value, $key){...});`